# Forbidden 403 while trying to save <><> chracters with Ajax & jQuery using $_POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

i'm trying to $_POST characters to my php file to save in a database the data of a form.

There is my procedure :

```
$("#save").on("click",function(el){ 
        el.preventDefault();
        var text = "<h1>test</h1><h1>test</h1>";
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {_text:text},
            url:  'ajax/do_save.php',
            success: function(data) {
                if(data == "0"){
                    console.log("fail");
                }
                else if(data != "0"){
                    //console.log("success");
                }
            }
        });
});
```

The php file is not the problem, it's really in this ajax call and the tags <>.

When var text = "<> <>" it crash, and i got the following error :

> 403 (Forbidden)

But when var text = "<> <", everything is ok the post is Successful and i've got no error and the save is well done in the database.

So, what do you guys think it can be? Seriously, I am totally lost, cause this EXACTLY same code in a precedent project and it work's like a charm. I don't know what I can do now.

Comment: Try HTML encoding your string

Comment: Certain web hosting companies install filtering software on their servers which blocks POSTed html (an attempt to prevent HTML injection).  If nothing else, you could url encode it before posting.

Comment: It's exactly on the same serveur

Comment: Are you using any framework for this project?

Comment: If the string is the same on the server, then this is obviously a server-side error, so you'll need to show your server-side code.

Comment: On the server code I put an echo 1; and I receive nothing. The request never reach the .php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a server issue. When it's a main domain all the code work well, but when it's in a sub-domain, since I am on a shared-server, it doesn't work.

Hope it can help some one !

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the elements using [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).

```
var text = encodeURI("<h1>test</h1><h1>test</h1>");
```

Then on the backend you'd use [`urldecode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php);

```
$html = urldecode($_POST['_text']);
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ndS25/)

---

Alternatively you could simple store the encoded string in the database then decrypt it when you need to use it.

Comment: I'll try that now and I'll keep you in touch

Comment: When I try: <h1>test</h1> it works. The data send to my ajax file is : %3Ch1%3Etest%3C/h1%3E . But when I try <h1>test</h1><h1>test</h1> for example, it crash and the data sent is : %3Ch1%3Etest%3C/h1%3E%3Ch1%3Etest%3C/h1%3E

Comment: just try encodeURIComponent and I still have the same problem.